# HTML/CSS Данный код валидный наименованию классов по БЭМ?

Tags: html, css, классы, бэм

```
<div class="skill">
  <div class="skill__item">
    <div class="skill-text>
      <p class="skill-text__title">...</p>
      <p class="skill-text__percent">...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: да (нужно 12 символов)

Comment: @meine что значит 18 символов?

Comment: Чтобы оставлять комментарии нужно не менее 15 символов.